# How to get the time zone of a guest user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to get the time zone of a user who is not logged in. And then convert the post's created_at time to that time zone?

I searched the web but i did not get any post which relates a guest user's time zone.

In my application.rb file I set the time zone as:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining a web user's time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone)

Comment: I whould discourage you from doing that. Its a better solution to store the users timezone in the users model and change the created at time in the view not in the database. You would lose the possibility to track the "real" time it was created.

Comment: @davidb you are right and that is straight forward. When there is an object then there is no problem. But I want it for a guest user who doesn't reside in database and doesn't have any object.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you already have guest_user in any object, to actually use that user's time zone the most common pattern is to simply create a private method in your ActionController and run it as an around filter.

```
around_filter :user_time_zone, :if => :guest_user

def user_time_zone(&block)
 Time.use_zone(guest_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

Hope this will help. Thanks